# JSONException getting the key value

Tags: java, json

My JSON for "Students" looks like the below example.

```
{
"phone":"703-703-1234",
"poc":"XYZ",
"name":"ABC",
"location":"California",
"id":10,
"deletedBy":null,
"statusObj":{
      "descr":"IN PROGRESS",
      "id":10},
"createDate":1595396946000,
"deleteDate":null}
```

My code to get the child elements is this:

```
JSONArray data = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Students");
for(int i=0; i<data.length(); i++){
if(data.getJSONObject(i).has("statusObj") && !data.getJSONObject(i).isNull("statusObj")){
    JSONObject status = (JSONObject)data.getJSONObject(i).get("statusObj");
    Iterator iterator = status.keys();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        String key = (String)iterator.next();
        System.out.println("Descr is ..- "+key);
        //JSONObject page = status.getJSONObject(key);
        JSONObject page = status.getJSONObject("descr");
        System.out.println("Descr is - "+page);
    }
}
}
```

I am getting the following exception when I try to get the "descr" obj

```
Descr is ..- descr
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["descr"] is not a JSONObject.
    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:557)
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear. The key `"descr"` doesn't refer to an object. If you look at your example data, it is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception really says it all - the key `"descr"` doesn't refer to an object, but to a string. You should use `getString` instead:

```java
String page = status.getString("descr");
```